# Singing along with a song while listening to another

Tags: audio

I want to sing along to a kareoke version of a song while listening to the origional at the same time. How can I accomplish this to have them play in sync from the same source, say my phone. I want the karoke to play on a pa system and the origonal to play via headphones. Bluetooth and av jacks are available.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but unless the two tracks are perfectly time aligned (improbable) I don't see any way to come near of what you ask.

I suggest making a mix of both songs into a single playback file  (e.g. .wav or .mp3)

Use an audio editor like Audacity, import the audio files of the original and the karaoke into different tracks, mix the two tracks as required (e.g. original to left and karaoke to right) and export the audio.

You may have a bit of difficulty precisely  aligning the two tracks in time. Even if they are produced at the exact tempo, some misalignment is bound to exist between two differently produced tracks. If the differences are not too big, you may be able to align the two tracks by using a time compression /expansion  filter on parts of each track.
I'm assuming the karaoke version follows the precise same song structure as the original  (if that's not the case you may still be able to splice the two versions in Audacity so that they align).

It's a work of patience and may be virtually impossible if there are significant time jitters in either of the tracks.

Some sw exists as plugins for high end DAWs that automatically detect beats (where percussion or other rythm cues exist that may be detected by the sw) and automatically renders the track in a fully uniform tempo from start to end. But they're rather expensive pieces of sw and require at least some audio production experience to be used.

Now, to have each track going to a different output you need to use some sort of mixer and route the channels appropriately.

Comment: Alternately, you could record yourself (or someone else) singing along on the karaoke track instead of mixing the original and the karaoke tracks. OP: It might help if you explained the problem you're trying to solve.